# Subqueries in Cypher QL

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to have a subquery in Cypher QL? The problem that I am facing right now is to find triads. I am using the code below:

```
START n=node(*) MATCH triad=nbrl--n--nbrr RETURN count(triad)
```

The problem with the query above is it counts the triads two times. For example both 

    `B -- A -- C`

and

    `C -- A -- B`

are returned as triads.

My plan is to get rid of one the `nbrl--n--nbrr` xor `nbrr--n--nbrl`. But I can't think of anything but subquery to do so. Any help is highly appreciated. 

Update:

Found another problem. Consider the graph below:

```
A -- B
```

Query `START n=node(*) MATCH triad=nbrl--n--nbrr RETURN triad` returns:

```
A | B | A
B | A | A
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
START n=node(*) MATCH triad=nbrl-->n--nbrr RETURN count(triad)
```

Comment: The problem is my graphs are not directed so all the edges (relationships in Cypher QL) are bidirectional. That basically means there is no difference between `nbrl--n--nbrr` and `nbrl-->n--nbrr`.